# Picamera image variation: What parameter should I adjust?

Tags: pi-4, picamera

I am capturing images using the picamera v2 noir and avering the pixel values to see what variation of intensities I have during the video.
The problem is that, even when the image is still and I am only using sunlight, I see a variation in the signal.
I was wondering which parameter is autoajusting the image and making that variation.

These are the parameters I have defined:

```
cam = PiCamera()
cam.resolution = (720, 960)
cam.framerate = 20
cam.exposure_mode = 'off'
cam.brightness = 50
cam.iso = 0
cam.shutter_speed = 1000
```